# multiple pagination in django class based view

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-views, django-class-based-views

The code below paginates the queryset but how can I paginate context['guser1']

```
class AuthorList(ListView):
    template_name = 'authorList.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Author.objects.order_by('date')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AuthorList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if int(self.kwargs['user_id']) != self.request.user.id:
        raise PermissionDenied
    if self.request.user.username == 'guest':
        raise PermissionDenied
    context['guser1'] = Author.objects.order_by('date').filter(
                 real_date__lte=datetime.now()).filter(
                 created_by=int(self.kwargs['user_id']))

    context['guser'] = User.objects.filter(pk=int(self.kwargs['user_id']))
    return context
```

Comment: The `User` queryset will only contain one entry (or no entries at all) if you are filtering by `pk`, so it's not clear why you want to paginate it.

Comment: update the code, I was trying to make it so simple.