# multiple pagination in django class based view - listview

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

The code below paginates the queryset but how can I paginate context['guser1']

```
class AuthorList(ListView):
    template_name = 'authorList.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Author.objects.order_by('date')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AuthorList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['guser1'] = Author.objects.order_by('date')
    return context
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336284/multiple-pagination-in-django-class-based-view

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a `Paginator` object like you would in a view. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view).

Comment: can you give an example on how to do it with class based views.

Answer (score 0):

The paginator for the view can be accessed under the context variable `page_obj` in your template. The page number is passed as a GET parameter in the url, `page`. Here's a simple example:

```
{% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a href="{% url "your_view_url" %}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous page</a>
{% endif %}
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a href="{% url "your_view_url" %}?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next page</a>
{% endif %}
```